# fopen() - permission denied - despite having correct permissions (as far as I can tell)

Tags: php, apache, fopen, chmod

Recently moved server and trying to get everything set up. My memcache class writes logs, something I need for development.

edit: server running Ubuntu 12.04.

the webroot is
/var/www/public_html

the log file is in /var/www/logs/

Here are the directory permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       1415 Sep  6 11:53 default
drwxrwxr-x 2 root webmasters 4096 Sep  6 12:48 logs
drwxrwxr-x 8 root webmasters 4096 Sep  6 12:32 public_html
```

Here are the permissions from /var/www/logs

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root webmasters 116103 Sep  6 13:02 access.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root webmasters  16094 Sep  6 12:48 error.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root webmasters      0 Sep  6 12:48 memcache.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root webmasters   9861 Sep  6 13:02 php_log.log
```

The file being browser to is /var/www/public_html/index.php

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root webmasters 5660 Sep  6 01:51 /var/www/public_html/index.php
```

Index includes /var/www/public_html/includes/cache.php

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root webmasters 4602 Sep  6 12:47 /var/www/public_html/includes/cache.php
```

Group members:

```
grep 'webmasters' /etc/group
webmasters:x:1002:sftp_chris,www-data
```

I have even tried changing /logs and /memcache.log to chmod 777.

Not really understanding why this is happening, as you can see php is writing its log file to /logs/php.log without issue.

Any ideas? I'm absolutely baffled.

I thought maybe it had something to do with php-suhosin but couldn't find anything there.

the function:

```
function write_to_log($string){

    $file = '/var/www/memcache.log';
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a');
    $contents = @fread($fh, filesize($file));
    $stringData = $contents."[".date('H.i:s d-m-y')."] ".$string;
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Am I right you have wrong path in PHP func? You tell your log is in `/var/www/public_html/` but you're trying to write to `/var/www/`.

Comment: @zysoft, to do him a justice, he tells his log in `/var/www/logs`, not `/var/www/public_html`.

Comment: Here's the quote - `the log file is in /var/www/public_html`. Maybe the question should be edited. It is a bit confusing, but isn't different. Path is still wrong :)

Comment: oops, yes, @zysoft, sorry ;-)

Comment: Ow wow feel a bit silly there. Wasted a good hour and half fiddling with permissions and pulling my hair out! And @zysoft log was in /www/logs but I wrote wrong in Question. Although fixed now. :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the question, @ChrisB! Hope changing the path helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write to `/var/www/memcache.log`, not `/var/www/logs/memcache.log` for which you show permissions.

(why do you read the log before writing to it?)

Comment: Ow wow. I've spent so long fiddling with permissions and this is all it was :s. Clearly far too tired to be working. Apologies for the pointless question! Is there a way to simply append to a file? To be honest didn't really look up, I assumed it would have to be read and appended to!

Comment: @ChrisB You're already using it. fopen($file, `a`) = `Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.`. Just use `fwrite` and define the new lines that you want to add.

Comment: better yet, don't use fopen/fwrite use the much simpler AND much faster file_put_contents (with the FILE_APPEND flag) like so: file_put_contents( $log_filename, 'NEW LOG LINE' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );